# How to set up an email alert whenever a new azure data factory instance is created in any subscription within same organization

Tags: azure, factory, azure-data-factory

I want to know how to set up an email alert whenever a new data factory instance is created in any subscription(e.g. Dev, UAT, Prod) within the same organization.
I only want it on ADF creation and not on Update on ADF.

Comment: Also I want to capture the details who created the ADF instance, for which location(region) its created, etc.

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be using Azure Monitor Alert Rules, but it is not possible to assign it on organization level, you have to create one rule for each subscription.

The easiest way is to use default notification mechanism but, it will trigger on both create and update event type. If you want to filter it, use action with logicApp/Function method where you can apply your own custom logic to filter event, add more information (e.g. region) and send mails.

1. Go to Azure Monitor and click "New Alert rule"

[image]

2. Choose a subscription and 'Data Factory' as resource type

[image]

3. Choose "Create or update" signal

[image]

4. Add email for notification/action to trigger

[image]

5. Create a rule

Default mail looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Tomasz. I will try this option. I have few questions - 1. So does the rule also trigger email even on Update of a Data Factory because the operation name is "Create or Update". I just want the email alert on ADF creation only. 2. What should be the rule evaluation frequency?

Comment: Define Action then, not notification. On Action choose logicApp or Function, filter only create logs, and then send mails. You can also use some custom logic to get more info like region.